# What is the limit for number of servers in consul cluster?

Tags: consul

How many servers can consul handle? 10.000 - possible? 100.000?

I have an idea to implement configuration management system using it, and it is going to be a lot of nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard upper limit, as James Phillips has answered [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/3300):

> As long as your servers can handle the read/write loads you should be
>   fine with thousands of agents. We have folks in the 10's of thousands
>   of agents territory in a single datacenter.